# The Order of Operations with Brackets

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

How would one go about answering something like

```
-8-(-2)[4-(-5)]?
```

The problem here really isn't very complicated once one is used to getting down the right direction and order. Which would I do first and how would I go about moving on and finding the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your example

$$\begin{align} -8-(-2)[4-(-5)] &= -8-(-2)[4+5]&\text{resolve innermost parentheses}\\
&=-8-(-2)\cdot 9&\text{perform addition to get rid of brackets}\\
&=-8-(-18)&\text{multiplication preceeds add/sub}\\
&=-8+18&\text{as in first step}\\
&=10.&\text{done. Or first note that this is $18-8$.}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, Hagen!

Answer (score 3):

Never forget the order of operations:

1. Parentheses
2. Exponents
3. Multiplication / Division
4. Addition / Subtraction

In practice, this works out as such:

\begin{align}
-8-(-2)(4-(-5)) &= -8-(-2)(4-(-5))\\
&= -8-(-2)(4+5)\\
&= -8-(-2)(9)\\
&= -8-(-18)\\
&= -8+18\\
&= 10
\end{align}
Remember that the first step is always to evaluate what's inside the parentheses. The expressions surrounded by the most parentheses take precedence.